# C++ vector storing base class pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, vector

Ok, situation:
I am using a library that I have no control over, which has a method createSomeObject().
This method returns a pointer to an abstract base class with pure virtual functions, and it has no copy constructor so I can't instantiate it myself nor copy it (obviously).

I need to store some number (let's say 10) of these in a vector, so I tried to do the following:

```
vector<AbstractBaseClass*> v(10);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    v.push_back(library->createSomeObject());
}
```

As soon as this loop is over, the vector is filled with broken pointers.

I have tried the following:

```
vector<AbstractBaseClass*> v(10);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    AbstractBaseClass* abc = library->createSomeObject();
    v.push_back(abc);
}
```

To no avail.  I must be going crazy or doing something seriously wrong here.  I've looked around but the answer is always use boost::shared_ptr.  A great solution possibly, but I can't guarantee that it'll be on the machines that this will be built on, so I'd like to avoid packaging Boost with the code.

Is there something I'm missing?  I feel as though I'm just forgetting some simple thing, as I can't think of a reason one of these wouldn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do this:

```
vector<AbstractBaseClass*> v(10);
```

you're already creating a vector which contains 10 (NULL) pointers. So after you've called `push_back`, you'll have a vector with 20 pointers, out of which the first 10 are invalid.

If you know the size beforehand:

```
vector<AbstractBaseClass*> v(10);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    v[i] = library->createSomeObject();
}
```

or, alternitively, call `reserve` after creating an empty vector.

Comment: Aww dammit I was afraid of this: I'm retarded.  Will accept when the timer's down.

Comment: > 10 (dangling) pointers... Why are you calling them dangling? These are 10 NULL pointers.

Comment: @KirillKobelev I don't think they're initialized to NULL. Are they?

Comment: @KirillKobelev :) MSVS tends to be weird. I'm not saying they're not, but a standard reference counts as evidence, not one compiler's behavior.

Comment: In my defense, null is also dangling :P @KirillKobelev

Comment: From C++11, 23.3.6.2: explicit vector(size_type n);
3 Effects: Constructs a vector with n value-initialized elements.
4 Requires: T shall be DefaultConstructible.
5 Complexity: Linear in n.

Comment: Note `value-initialized` and `DefaultConstructible`.