# Creating a container to store multiple types

Tags: c++, containers

I have a class which contains pure virtual functions. I am using this class to make sure I do not forget to implement some methods in derived classes.

I have a collection of derived classes like

```
class B : public A
class C : public A
class D : public A 
etc
```

How can I create a container that can hold all of these derived classes (B,C,D)? I would prefer to use a standard container such as vector. I tried creating a vector of the base class but this results in the derived classes being converted if they are pushed onto the vector leading to a compilation error of invalid new-expression of abstract class type.

My base class:

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    virtual ~A();

    virtual double GetVolume() = 0;
};
```

Example derived class:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    B(){};
    virtual ~B(){};

    double GetVolume(){};
};
```

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I dont think this is an appropriate dupe, the answer here is not likely going to be a `boost::any` type, but a factory method and storing a `std::shared_ptr` to `A` ...

Comment: @Ben Vote to reopen then.

Comment: Maybe closer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895163/c-vector-storing-base-class-pointers, but not really ...

Comment: It's probably a duplicate of *something*, but that is not the correct duplicate, for sure. In this question you have an inheritance hierarchy, in the linked question they are three unrelated types. Now this user is going to use variant/any instead of simple polymorphism... IMHO this is actively misleading and a disservice to the user.

Comment: How about this one instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34383979/c-vector-of-base-class-objects

Comment: Use a vector of pointers rather than objects.

Comment: I think `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>` is probably what you need - storing pointers allows virtual dispatch and prevents object slicing.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a container of pointer-to-base. A container of base objects causes conversion from derived to base, which is called *slicing*. When you have a pointer-to-base however, the object can still have a different type (a derived one) than the base class, this is called the *dynamic type* of the object (as opposed to static type).

In modern C++ it's best to use smart pointers for this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> x;
x.push_back(std::make_unique<B>());
x.push_back(std::make_unique<C>());
x.push_back(std::make_unique<D>());

for (auto& e : x) {
    e->GetVolume();
}
```

Comment: would it be better to use emplace_back vs push_back?

Comment: @Adam It doesn't make too much difference in a situation like this. Because unique_ptr is so trivial and cheap to move, performance won't matter much, and anyway calling push_back without reserve is not going to have great performance. If I already have the object or something implicitly convertible to the object, I generally prefer push_back to emplace_back where perf isn't an issue. The function signature is much simpler; you get better error messages if you mess up and better help from the IDE.